# Convert Collection of shared_ptr into collection of weak_ptr

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14

I'd love to find a way to automatically convert containers of convertible types into each other.

for example, I'd like for this to exist:

```
template<typename Collection, typename T>
Collection<std::weak_ptr<T> > convert(const Collection<std::shared_ptr<T> > &c){
    Collection<std::weak_ptr<T> > l;
    for (auto &e : c) l.push_back(e);
    return l;
}
```

I effectively want to remove a layer of instantiated templates from the type of the argument, and re-instantiate it with a different templated type.

Even more ideally, I could write a convert function which works more generally; i.e. doesn't assume the existence of push_back and isn't specialized for just the case where shared_ptr converts into weak_ptr.

Does anyone have some idea if this is possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This function exists and is called `std::copy`.

```
 Collection1 a;
 Collection2 b;

 std::copy(std::begin(a), std::end(a), std::back_inserter(b));
```

This works for any collections as long as `std::back_inserter` is defined for the target container and the respective elements are convertible.

If you need to support something without `back_inserter`, you need to supply your own iterator to `std::copy` and make sure it works for your container.

If you want to keep the collection "type" and just swap the template parameter, you can use this:

```
template <template<typename> class OutPtr,
          template<typename> class InPtr,
          template<typename, typename> class Coll,
          typename Elem, typename Alloc>
auto transform_ptr_collection(const Coll<InPtr<Elem>, Alloc>& in) ->
                          Coll<OutPtr<Elem>, Alloc>
{
  return Coll<OutPtr<Elem>, Alloc>(std::begin(in), std::end(in));
}

// call it

suto out = transform_ptr_collection<std::weak_ptr>(vector_of_shared_ptr);
```

but I would not recommend it. Prefer iterator interfaces over collection interfaces, they are more general and easier to work with.

Comment: But how, in the templated setting I'm describing, do I figure out which collection I should construct with std::copy? I'd like Collection2 to be Collection1 but with a (known) template parameter swapped out for a different (known) template parameter.

Comment: You can use template template parameters to achieve this. See update.

Answer (score 3):

The standard containers have range constructors which allow you to construct them from a convertible container:

```
std::vector<std::weak_ptr<Foo>> weak_vec(shared_vec.begin(), shared_vec.end());
```

Or for less standard containers, use `std::copy`. For something that can cheaply be default constructed like `std::weak_ptr` I would construct a container of the correct size first then use `std::copy`:

```
std::vector<std::weak_ptr<Foo>> weak_vec(shared_vec.size());
std::copy(std::begin(shared_vec), std::end(shared_vec), std::begin(weak_vec));
```

For something that is not so cheap to default construct you can use `std::back_inserter`:

```
std::copy(std::begin(shared_vec), std::end(shared_vec), std::back_inserter(weak_vec));
```